# Why is the deprecated Date(String) called for @DateTimeFormat in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, date

I have a field that his being retrieved from a **MongoDB** like so:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy", lenient=OptBoolean.TRUE)
    private Date createDate;
```

It is stored as a `String` in the following format:

```
createdDate: "2019-01-20 15:45:00"
```

But I keep getting the following error when I try to fetch from the DB:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '2019-01-20 15:45:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191)
....

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.base/java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:617)
    at java.base/java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:275)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:108)
```

The reason for this error is because a deprecated method called [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-) is being called. **I can replicate the same error using:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    
        Date date = new Date("2019-01-20 15:45:00");
        System.out.println(date); 
    }
```

This gives the same `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:617)
    at java.base/java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:275)
    at com.tatadigital.product.DateTest.main(DateTest.java:15)
```

I would like to know 2 things:

1. Why is a deprecated method being called for conversion ? Is that not a bug ?
2. Also how can I workaround this ?